# (secret != guess) != заменяет оператору ==, как?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int guess;

  srand ( time(NULL) );         // инициализация функции rand значением функции time

  int secret = rand() % 10 + 1; // сгенерировать секретное число

  do {
    cout << "otgadayte (ot 1 do 10): ";
    cin >> guess;

    if (secret < guess) cout << "sekretnoe chislo meshe\n";
    else
        if (secret > guess) cout << "sekretnoe chislo bolshe\n";
  } while (secret != guess);

  cout << "pozdravlyayu\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Программа хорошо работает.
(secret != guess) почему знак != (не равен) меняет свое предназначение, ведь в программе, по логике, сгенерированное число необходимо чтобы совпадало с вводным числом для отображения "ПОЗДРАВЛЯЮ".

Объясните ПЖ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не ясно, почему вы считаете, что "знак != меняет свое предназначение".

У вас в программе оператор `!=` содержится только в условии цикла `do/while`. Этот цикл занимается запросом от пользователя очередного числа и проверкой его на правильность. Условие, указанное в части `while(...)` цикла `do/while` является условием *продолжения* выполнения цикла. Именно *продолжения*, как и во всех остальных типах циклов в С и С++.

То есть фактически условие `secret != guess` в этом цикле означает: если число *не угадано*, то *продолжать* выполнять цикл, т.е. *продолжать* запрашивать новые числа от пользователя.

Никакой "смены предназначения" тут нет.